# How can i convert string value from path param to int in Mapping templates of aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, vtl

I try to using api gateway and query data direct to dynamo db.
I has epoch time in path param and i tried to minus epoch by one day to query data in dynamodb but it not work. I tried convert by Interger.paserInt and some way but not work
Please help me
This is my body mapping templates

```
#set($epoch = $input.params('epoch'))
#set($secondInADay = 43200)
#set($start = $epoch - $secondInADay)

{
    "TableName":"my-table",
    "KeyConditionExpression":"#type_alias=:v1 AND epoch BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
        ":v1":{"S":"m"},
        ":startTime":{"N":"$util.urlDecode($start.toString())"},
        ":endTime":{"N":"$util.urlDecode($epoch.toString())"}
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#type_alias":"my hashkey"}
}
```

Comment: Whats the partition and sort key for your table?

Comment: My sort key name 'epoch'

Comment: So what happens when you execute it?

Comment: When execute value of $start is blank, i think may be $epoch is string so it cant minus for $secondInADay. This is my log:
```
Fri Nov 10 08:42:01 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{
    "TableName":"my-table",
    "KeyConditionExpression":"#type_alias=:v1 AND epoch BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
        ":v1":{"S":"m"},
        ":startTime":{"N":""},
        ":endTime":{"N":"100000000"}
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#type_alias":"type"}
}

```

Comment: And when you try with valid dates?

Comment: yep, i tried to pass epoch date in path param and i want to query 12hour ago in dynamodb, but i cant convert epoch to number to minus by 12hour

Answer (score 1):

To convert it to a number you can use the following syntax:

```
$Integer.parseInt($input.params('epoch'))
```

Comment: I tried that but not work for me
`#set($epochNumber = $Integer.parseInt($input.params('epoch')))
#set($start = $epochNumber - 0)`

Comment: Whats the request output?